# Virtualbox VM changes ethX ip after some time

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, apache-http-server

Today I needed to test some things on a local webserver, and since I already have apache installed by default on a linux VM (backtrack 5) I decided to do it there instead of installing WAMP on my W7 host. So I changed the VM network settings to Bridged Adapter, then I started apache on the linux VM, ran the **ifconfig** command which shows something like:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:24:53:57:84  
          inet addr:192.168.0.25  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:31851 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27133139 (27.1 MB)  TX bytes:4781908 (4.7 MB)
```

Then I opened ***192.168.0.25*** on firefox on my host machine and it worked fine, I am able to access the apache running on linux from my w7 host machine.

The problem is that after 30 minutes or so, the *inet addr* on linux increases by one, for example changes from ***192.168.0.25*** to ***192.168.0.26***, another 30 minutes later and the ip changes again to **.27**, etc. And I am not touching anything to change it.

**What could be causing this? Or how do I set it up so the ip is always the same?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it editing */etc/network/interfaces*

```
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.99
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```